# Pause resource creation in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a template that allows users to define a S3 Bucket. In the same template, I have options to add a Lambda Trigger, a SQS Trigger and an SNS Trigger.

In order to successfully create the S3 Bucket with optional triggers, I need to create the Policies for the selected triggers.

The problem I am facing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not due to race condition. If the Bucket is created before the policies, stack creation fails.

I have tried to add conditional DependsOn property on S3 Bucket resource but DependsOn only accepts string.

This is how my DependsOn attribute looked like:

```
"S3Bucket": {
    "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
    "DependsOn": [{
        "Fn::If": ["DoCreateQueueTrigger",
        "SQSMessagePermission",
        ""]
    }],

}
```

The only thing i can think of is pause the template execution before it reaches to Bucket creation.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I haven't got time to check it, so not 100% sure if this will work, but you could try returning `{"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue" }` instead of `""` for the else condition of the `"Fn::If"`?

Comment: I have tried that too. it does not work.

Comment: Had one more idea - put the policies into a nested stack, and have the bucket depend on the nested stack.  The nested stack will only be considered complete when all its resources are completed.  The created policies can be passed out as a nested stack output if you need to reference them in other resources.

Comment: havent tried that yet but if I think i will run into the same situation there too. I will have to use dependson attribute in master template to not execute child templates that do not need to be created

Comment: for now i have put the policy references in metadata. Since i can put conditions there, it creates the internal dependency and works fine. No race condition. Not sure what will be side effect of it but untill i find the right solution, this will do.

Comment: With the child templates, I would always create the child template, and then let the child template decide which policies to create.  Then the child template will always exist and if no policies are created it will complete immediately and allow the 'DependsOn' dependency to be considered fulfilled.  If some policies are created, then the child template will only be complete when all conditional policies are created.  But - it sounds like you have a solution for now!

Comment: One way you could do this using multiple Bucket Resources and specifying Conditions on those - although you would have to write the combinatorial of all your optional triggers... :/

Comment: Nested Stacks did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by declaring two identically-named, reciprocal Conditional Resources: one declaring the optional trigger, the other a 'null resource' that simply accepts the `DependsOn` declaration when the real resource isn't actually created:

```
Conditions:
  DoCreateTrigger: !Equals [!Ref CreateTrigger, true]
  NotCreateTrigger: !Not [!Equals [!Ref CreateTrigger, true]]
Resources:
  SQSMessagePermission:
    Condition: NotCreateTrigger
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
  SQSMessagePermission:
    Condition: DoCreateTrigger
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      # ...etc...
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: [SQSMessagePermission]
    Properties:
      # ...etc...
```